# Loop for taking sum of rows based on proximity to other non-NA rows

Tags: r, loops, dataset, stat, genetics

I have a dataset with 2 important columns, `Position` and `Count`. There are a total of 34,532 rows, but only 457 non-NA values in the `Count` column (every cell in `Position` column has a value). I need to write a loop to march down the rows, and if there are 2 rows in `Count` where there is only 1 `NA` row between them, sum the two values up and print only one row with the summed Count value and the Position value that corresponds to the larger Count value, thus making the three rows into one. For example:

```
Position Count
15       15
22       NA
38       NA
49        5
55       NA
61       17
```

would become

```
Position Count
15        15
22        NA
38        NA
61        22
```

After this step, I also need to write another script to march down the rows and look for rows with only two NA's between non-NA rows in Count. This would make the previous data become

```
Position Count
61        37
```

Ideally I would like a loop that can be flexibly adjusted to the number of NA's in between adjacent non-NA values that can be freely changed. I would greatly appreciate any insight for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far?  What is not working?  Where are you encountering difficulties?

Comment: What would you do in a case where your vector with NA looked like, say, `5, NA, 17, NA, 5`?  Just add the first and third values?  What about the third and fifth values?

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to logistically figure out what needs to be done. I believe I need to first march down the column Counts by 3 rows at a time (count[i]...count[i+2]), and if the first and third cells are not NA (is.na=N), and the cell between the two is NA, then the values (sum[__]) and print the correspond Position row. My R skills are not strong, so while I can rationalize what I need to do, putting it into practice with loops is the roadblock.

Comment: If the vector was "5, NA, 17, NA, 5" in that order, I would first sum 5 and 17 (=22) and print that along with the position that corresponds to 17, and then sum 22 and 5 and print that along with the position that corresponds to 22.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do I *think* these functions should for for you. You coudl easily rewrite the `removeAllNA()` function to be a loop instead of recursive if you prefer, but using the vectorized functions in `removeNA()` will a lot faster than doing the whole thing with loops:

```
## df - data frame with Count and Position variables
## n - the number of consecutive NA values to rollup
removeNA <- function(df,n=1){
  #remove any leading NA values
  if(is.na(df$Count)[1]) df <- df[-(1:(which(!is.na(df$Count))[1]-1)),]
  #remove any ending NA values
  if(tail(is.na(df$Count),1)) df <- df[-(nrow(df):(tail(which(!is.na(df$Count)),1)+1)),]
  #get the indices for non NA values
  i <- which(!is.na(df$Count))
  #get the indices for the non NA values to rollup to based on the inputed "n"
  i <- i[diff(i) == n+1] + 1
  #return the data frame if no values to rollup
  if(length(i) == 0) return(df)
  #remove any values are out of range
  i <- i[i < nrow(df)]
  #rollup variables
  df$Count[i+n] <- df$Count[i+n] + df$Count[i-1]
  #remove variables that were included in rollup
  return(df[-c(sapply(1:n,function(x) i + x -1),i-1),])
}

removeAllNA <- function(df,n=1){
  if(!any(is.na(df$Count)) | n > nrow(df)){
    return(df)
  } else {
    df <- removeNA(df,n)
    removeAllNA(df,n+1)
  }
}
```

Your example:

```
> tst <- data.frame(Position=c(15,22,38,49,55,61),Count=c(15,NA,NA,5,NA,17))
> removeNA(tst,1)
  Position Count
1       15    15
2       22    NA
3       38    NA
6       61    22
> removeNA(removeNA(tst,1),2)
  Position Count
6       61    37
> removeAllNA(tst)
  Position Count
6       61    37
```

Bigger random example:

```
> set.seed(34)
> dat <- data.frame(Position=1:100,Count=round(runif(100,5,25)))
> dat$Count[sample(100,60)] <- NA
> removeAllNA(dat)
   Position Count
5         5    24
9         9    35
10       10    16
11       11    11
24       24    59
25       25    14
28       28    44
29       29    18
30       30    16
36       36    42
37       37     6
38       38    16
39       39    13
51       51    65
52       52    11
62       62    27
89       89    84
95       95    39
96       96    22
97       97     9
```

EDIT:
Adding second function:

```
addNotNA <- function(df){
  i <- which(!is.na(df$Count))
  i <- i[which(diff(i) == 1)] + 1
  if(length(i) == 0) return(df)
  df$Count[i] <- df$Count[i] + df$Count[i-1]
  return(df[-(i-1),])
}
> addNotNA(df)
  Position Count
2       22    36
3       38    NA
4       49     5
5       55    NA
6       61    17
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the removeNA method. This works as I imagined, except now I realize that there are many instances in the data where multiple non-NA values occur directly adjacent of each other in the Count column; (ie. 15, 2, 7, NA, NA, 20, NA). Could you point me toward the part of your code that I need to adjust the parameter for to sum adjacent counts that do not have NA's in between them as well, while still printing the Position corresponding to the largest count.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking for. I can add some comments to spell out what the function is doing (sorry for it being so ugly -- I didn't want to spend time cleaning it up if it didn't do what you wanted) but I'll need some more concrete examples to understand what you're asking for now.

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. In the first example I had it showed 

Position Count
15       15
22       NA
38       NA
49        5
55       NA
61       17

and your script works great in summing the Count cells that have one NA separating non-NA values. Now I found out that the data actually has non-NA values without any NA separating them

Comment: For example


    Position Count
    15       15
    22       21
    38       NA
    49        5
    55       NA
    61       17

So, now I am looking to add an extra step to the analysis, before the previous script. I need to add up the adjacent Count values that do not have any NA between them first and printing the position corresponding to the largest Count value, resulting in


    Position Count
    22       36
    38       NA
    49        5
    55       NA
    61       17

Comment: Sorry again, having difficulty formatting the example to table format in the comments. Here's an image with the correct format

http://i.imgur.com/xa79F8S.png?1

Comment: With the new addNotNA() function, for some reason it does not sum the counts for two adjacent, non-NA rows http://i.imgur.com/ZRkE0Uz.png?1 , but it however does seem to sum two adjacent rows if three rows in a row exist, but does not sum all three http://i.imgur.com/HLQBmLi.png?1

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you wanted before. I edited the function so give the new one a try.